# Разбор документа. Просто алгоритм.

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Исходный документ

```
.wrap { .header {} .main{} .footer{} }
```

На выходе должно быть(ну можно и без отсутпов):

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Покажите пример алгоритма на русском языке хотя бы или на яп каком-н. реализующий это чудо. Или ссылку на статью по теме. Надеюсь, это называется парсинг, хотя могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Ваш входной документ описывается простой грамматикой, так что вполне подойдёт простой [парсер рекурсивного спуска](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: хм..обычная в общем-то вузовская программа уже считается чудом?

Comment: @DreamChild: Спасибо за ценный комментарий.